# How to redirect user after logout from ADFS?

Tags: redirect, active-directory, adfs

I have a page that authenticate using ADFS and it have logout but it don't logout from ADFS only from the site. How can I logout from ADFS and then redirect to a page from my site? I've try this url:

```
https://{auth-server}/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignout1.0&wreply=https://example.com/landingPage
```

it logout but don't redirect back to my site, how can I redirect to certain page after logout?

Answer (score 2):

Hey it's old but this solution might help someone in need some day :D.

The page to which you are to redirecting needs to be in the adfs trusted page lists. If it's not present in the trusted URI, ADFS just ignore your request. So basically you can't redirect to https://example.com/landingPage if it's not a trusted URI.

It is thoroughly explained here :

https://www.sevecek.com/EnglishPages/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=93

I tried, Geh123's answer, it didn't work. You don't need the braces !

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
https://{auth-server}/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignout1.0&wreply={https://example.com/landingPage}
```

Note that there now are curly braces around the data of the `wreply` parameter.

Comment: Please provide an explanation.